# Symfony - The annotation was never imported

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, api-doc

I'm using Symfony framework and have intention do add auto-documentation engine to RESTful api of my project.

After some searching I've found apidoc engine (http://apidocjs.com/). It works pretty simple: you have to add some annotations for every controller of you RESTful api and documentation will generated.

The example of annotation is:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/dictionary_list/{userId}/{sessionKey}", name="api/dictionary_list")
 * @api {get} /api/dictionary_list/{userId}/{sessionKey} 01. Values list (ids) for all system dictionaries
 * @apiName Dictionary list
 * @apiGroup Dictionary
 *
 * @apiParam {Integer} userId  User's ID received in authorization request
 * @apiParam {String} sessionKey  Session key received in authorization request
 *
 * @apiSuccess {Integer} parcelStatuses  The name of current dictionary
 * @apiSuccess {String} itemId  Item id which used in requests
 * @apiSuccess {String} itemName  Item name
 */

public function dictionaryListAction($userId=null, $sessionKey=null)
{
 ...
}
```

As you can see, annotation for apidoc is the same as the annotation for routing in Symfony.

By the way in production environment it works fine, but in development environment I get exception like

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@apiName" in method AppBundle\Controller\Api\apiDictionaryController::dictionaryListAction() was never imported.
```

Is there any way to fix this issue and say to Symfony that annotation for apidoc have to be ignored?

Comment: discussed [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17000) also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `IgnoreAnnotation` annotation to tell Docrine annotation reader to skip this annotation in your controller. To do this, simply put the annotation  add `@IgnoreAnnotation("Annotation")` to the class doc comment of class.

In you case:

```
/**
 * @IgnoreAnnotation("apiName")
 * @IgnoreAnnotation("apiGroup")
 * @IgnoreAnnotation("apiParam")
 * @IgnoreAnnotation("apiSuccess")
 */
class ActionController extends Controller


/**
 * @Route("/api/dictionary_list/{userId}/{sessionKey}", name="api/dictionary_list")
 * @api {get} /api/dictionary_list/{userId}/{sessionKey} 01. Values list (ids) for all system dictionaries
 * @apiName Dictionary list
 * @apiGroup Dictionary
 *
 * @apiParam {Integer} userId  User's ID received in authorization request
 * @apiParam {String} sessionKey  Session key received in authorization request
 *
 * @apiSuccess {Integer} parcelStatuses  The name of current dictionary
 * @apiSuccess {String} itemId  Item id which used in requests
 * @apiSuccess {String} itemName  Item name
 */

public function dictionaryListAction($userId=null, $sessionKey=null)
{
 ...
}
```

You could also consider to open a PR to the [doctrine/annotations](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations) project to include this annotation as default skipped as [this one](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations/pull/34).

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony uses the [doctrine/annotations](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations) package to parse annotations. When it encounters an unkown annotation that hasn't been blacklisted it throws an exception.

You can blacklist additional annotations, see [Doctrine docs -  Ignoring missing exceptions](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html#ignoring-missing-exceptions):

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;

AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('api');
AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiParam');
AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiGroup');
AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiSuccess');
```

I'd put this in *app/autoload.php* since it's a global setting.

Comment: Thank you, but when I follow your advise I got such exception: `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader' not found in /home/alex/Projects/parcel-search/web-app/app/autoload.php on line 7.` What I've missed?

Comment: You need to put it after *require vendor/autoload.php* but before the `return`.

Answer (score 1):

Annotations are read during DI Container compilation so it may be a better idea to ignore the apidocs annotations during [compiler pass](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html).

Example:

```
<?php
namespace YourBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class IgnoreApiDocsAnnotationsPass implements CompilerPassInterface {
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container) {
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('api');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiDefine');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiDeprecated');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiDescription');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiError');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiErrorExample');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiExample');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiGroup');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiHeader');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiHeaderExample');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiIgnore');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiName');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiParam');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiParamExample');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiPermission');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiPrivate');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiSampleRequest');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiSuccess');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiSuccessExample');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiUse');
        AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('apiVersion');
    }
}
```

I obtainted the full list of annotation from the [apidoc docs](http://apidocjs.com/). You need to register the compiler pass in your bundle with

```
<?php
namespace YourBundle;

use YourBundle\DependencyInjection\IgnoreApiDocsAnnotationsPass;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class YourBundle extends Bundle {
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container) {
        parent::build($container);
        $container->addCompilerPass(new IgnoreApiDocsAnnotationsPass());
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to import Route :

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;