# The annotation "@Route" was never imported

Tags: symfony, routes

I am a student and I am very new in symfony and in stackoverflow then sorry if I do some mistakes.

Here is the error when I try to access to the page:

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Route" in method
>   AppBundle\Controller\FormController::newAction() was never imported.
>   Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation? in
>   /home/buddy/Bachelor/RealBachelor/src/AppBundle/Controller/ (which is
>   being imported from
>   "/home/buddy/Bachelor/RealBachelor/app/config/routing.yml"). Make sure
>   annotations are enabled.

and here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class SuccessController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/success", name="success")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {


        $id = "yeah success!!";

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'id' => $id,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I don't know if is needed but here is my routing config file:

```
 # bin/config/routing.yml
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony - The annotation was never imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152896/symfony-the-annotation-was-never-imported)

Comment: Your error message says FormController, but you code example says SuccessController. Are you sure you're looking at the right file?

Answer (score 17):

You need to check this file:

```
AppBundle\Controller\FormController.php
```

It seems you didn't add the namespace:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
```

In newer Symfony versions, use

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
```

Please check it.

Comment: In newer Symfony versions, use `Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route` instead.

Comment: Please add this as a new answer, as I latest Symfony (5.x) will use the Route file mentioned in @NepomukFrädrich

Comment: didn't change anything, the same error

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem just like yours and from a newly downloaded project with composer and symfony 3.4. It didn't start until I commented out the routing.yml file then I got the project up without problems.
I attach how it should look:

```
app/config/routing.yml

#app:
#    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
#    type: annotation
```

You save changes then you start the server and it should work without problems!

Regards!

Comment: lol, really works, but looks weird, thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should look like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/success", name="success")
 */
class SuccessController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {


        $id = "yeah success!!";

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
                'id' => $id,
        ]);
    }
}
```